# Is it possible to give optional URL parameter in grape route

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

Is it possible to give optional URL parameter in grape route.

Ie.
for a an endpoint like :

```
    get '/user/:name/:location/:id' do
    end
```

Is there any way to hit this endpoint with or without "location" parameter in the URL.

I tried defining endpoint with bracket for optional parameter as below :

```
    get '/user/:name/(:location)/:id' do
    end
```

But this did not work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use `location` as a query param. So that you'll be able to make it optional and to keep just 1 route.

```
params do
  optional :location, type: String
end

get '/user/:name/:id' do
  if params[:location].present?
    # some code
  else
    # some code
  end
end
```

This route will be matched by `/user/:name/:id?location={something}` with a location, and `/user/:name/:id` without.